# Change element css when div has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have problem with my code. What I want to do is change css of elemnt when I'm on first div. So, when I'm on first div my element have for example font-size: 24px; when I scroll down my element should have font-size: 40; I'm using wordpress and Vase theme. My site - http:///www.ciranga.pl

When I'm on main slide (with red background) I want to make my arrows on right to be white. When I scroll down I want it to be red. How Can I do that? Any help would be great.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if ($('.swiper-slide:first-of-type').hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
    $('.vase_whiteC').css('font-size', '40px');
} else {
    $('.vase_whiteC').css('font-size', '24px');
}
$('html').keydown(function(e) {

    var Key = e.keyCode;

    if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(Key) > -1) {

        // up!
        if (Key == 38) {
            $(".umicon-vase_arrowPrev").parent().trigger("click");
        }

        // down!
        if (Key == 40) {
            $(".umicon-vase_arrowNext").parent().trigger("click");
        }

        return false;
    }

});

});
```

Comment: I see you have code that allows the arrow in red at the page footer to be visible and hidden on page scroll. You can use the same method to add class that has a different width and color as per your requirement. Then you can add and remove such class to the element which has to change appearance. Also you have c class `vase_whiteC`  with  `color: #fff !important`. you need to remove that and switch red and white classes in scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the original poster, we have arrived at this solution:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function() { setButtonState(); });
arw = $('.sliderBtnWrapper [class*="vs_swiper-button"]').click(function() { setButtonState(); });

function setButtonState() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var sbw = $('.sliderBtnWrapper').children('.vs_swiper-button-prev-contentSlider.swiper-button-disabled').length;
        if(!sbw) {
            arw.css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            arw.css('color', 'white');
        }
    }, 600);
}
```

Comment: Adding [this link](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WPoRqfl96po) as a comment for future reference. The slider API has callback methods that can be used if someone cannot figure out how exactly it works (I personally can't).

Answer (score 1):

You can use other methods like `$(document).scroll(function(){`

Below code is not your answer but you can try something like that

var

```
 $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) { 
            // add css here
     }
  }
```

targetOffset would be 38,40.

Comment: The scroll event only fires once after page load, so this solution will, unfortunately, not work.